# How can I pass the current windows user credentials in an HTTP post in JAVA?

Tags: java, authentication, credentials, apache-commons-httpclient

I have a Java program that needs to make a post to a URL that requires authentication.  I don't want to specify a hardcoded user name and password, I just want to use the credentials of the user that is running the Java program.

I have gone through the different HTTPClient classes and I downloaded Waffle.  I just can't find the right combination to pull the current Windows user credentials and pass them along to the post request.

This code works:

```java
NTCredentials creds = new NTCredentials("user", "pass", "host", "domain");
HttpCLient client = new HttpClient;
HttpClient.getState().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, creds);
```

When I do my post, I get a 200 response. How can I do the same, but instead of building NTCredentials from hardcoded values, I pass along the credentials of the user running the java program?

I have tried Waffle:

```java
WindowsSecurityContextImpl context = new WindowSecurityContextImpl;
System.out.println(context.getPrincipalName());
```

I can retrieve the windows username. But I can't find a way to pass on the actual credentials to HttpClient.

Thanks.

Comment: Dont you think it would not be available to be read, as it would be a security hole then in Windows

Comment: You don't think the current signed on user should be able to have their authenticated credentials passed along in another request?

Answer (score -1):

Password cannot be retrieved. At best can fetch the user name, which you already did. 
For your case, where API authentication is required, API should have an API user with rotating passwords that could be used for accessing the service. 
If the access requires user specific credentials, there has to be prompt where password is provided by logged in user ( again ) before the system further executes the workflow

Comment: I don't want to retrieve the password.  I just want the currently signed on windows user's credentials passed along with my request. They have already been authenticated to the network. Something like the DefaultCredentials in .NET.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.credentialcache.defaultcredentials?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: No @Jonh, I think its not possible. The remote service needs to validate if user is already authenticated,  I think you need API protection and possibly API level credentials could be created and persisted on client side. Please see thi slink also if helpful : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/enable-windows-authentication-in-web-api-and-angular-app/